# 3d Graphing Application Questions

Tags: graphics, 3d, graphing, graph-visualization, rpn

For one of my classes, I made a 3D graphing application (using Visual Basic). It takes in a string (z=f(x,y)) as input, parses it into RPN notation, then evaluates and graphs the equation. While it did work, it took about 20 seconds to graph. I would have liked to add slide bars to rotate the graph vertically and horizontally, but it was definitely too slow to allow that.

Does anyone know what programming languages would be best for this type of thing? Ideally, I will be able to smoothly rotate the function once it is graphed.

Also, I’m trying to find a better way to rotate the function. Right now, I evaluate it at a bunch of points, and then plot the points to the screen. Every time it is rotated, it must be re-evaluated and plot all the new points. This takes just as long as the original graph process, as it basically treats it as a completely new function.

Lastly, I need a better way to display the graph. Currently (using VB with visual studio) I plot 200,000 points to a chart, but this does not look great by any means. Eventually, I would like to be able to change color based on height, and other graphics manipulation to make it look better.

To be clear, I am not asking for someone to do any of this for me, but rather the means to go about coding this in an efficient way. I will greatly appreciate any advice anyone can give to help with any of these three concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will explain how I would go about it using C++ and OpenGL. This doesn't mean those are the tools that you must use, it's just those are standard graphics tools.

Your function's surface is essentially a 2D manifold, which has the nice property of having an intuitive mapping to a 2D space. What is commonly referred to as UV mapping.

What you should do is pick the ranges for the rectangle domain you want to display (minimum x, maximum x, minimum y, maximum y) And make 2 nested for loops of the form:

```
// Pseudocode
for (x=minimum; x<maximum; x++)
    for (y=minimum; y=maximum; y++)
       3D point = (x,y, f(x,y))
```

Store all of these points into a container (std vector for c++ works fine) and this will be your "mesh".

This is done once, prior to rendering. You then render those points using, for example GL_POINTS, and rotate your graph mesh using rotations on the GPU.

This will only show scattered points, not a surface.

If you also wish to show the surface of your function, and not just the points, you can triangulate that set of points fairly easily.

Group each 4 contiguous vertices (i.e the vertices at indices `<x,y>, <x+1,y>, <x+1,y>, <x+1,y+1>)` and create the 2 triangles:

```
(<x,y>, <x+1,y>, <x,y+1>), (<x+1,y>, <x+1,y+1>, <x,y+1>)
```

This will fill triangulate the surface of your mesh.

Essentially you only need to build your mesh once, and this way rendering should be 60 fps for something with 20 000 vertices, regardless of whether you only render points or triangles too.

Answer (score 0):

Programming language is mostly not relevant, so VB itself is probably not the issue. You can have the same issues in Python, C#, C++, etc. Of course you must master the programming language you choose.

One key aspect is using the right algorithms and data-structures. Proper use of memory allocations and memory layout for maximizing CPU (and GPU) cache are also key. Then you must take advantage of the platform and hardware capabilities (GPU and Multithreading). For the last point you definetely need to use a graphics library such as OpenGL or Vulkan.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I had focused on readability and getting the project done quickly, so there are plenty of things that can be optimized. I will definitely look in to graphics libraries. My instructor said something about multi threading too, so I will learn more on that as well.